# SQL query to select all between dates in 2D Array

Tags: sql, arrays

I have an Array of Arrays and I need to select all the records (Array) that are in date range.
It looks like this when I print_r in PHP :

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [FlightID] => 1
                [[Flight from]] => Kraków
                [[Flight to]] => London
                [[Airport from name]] => Balice
                [[Airport to name]] => London Heathrow Airport
                [[Date]] => 2013-06-06
                [[Price for kid]] => 200
                [[Prcie for adult]] => 500
                [[Total seats]] => 100
                [[Free seats]] => 100
                [[Flight time]] => 12:00:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [FlightID] => 2
                [[Flight from]] => London
                [[Flight to]] => Kraków
                [[Airport from name]] => London Heathrow Airport
                [[Airport to name]] => Balice
                [[Date]] => 2013-06-14
                [[Price for kid]] => 200
                [[Prcie for adult]] => 500
                [[Total seats]] => 100
                [[Free seats]] => 100
                [[Flight time]] => 14:00:00
            )

    )
```

etc. I need to select the Array that is between 2013-06-03 and 2013-06-08 for example.
How would it look?

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE Date Between '2013-06-03' and '2013-06-08'
```

is not working, but I guess it's due to 2D array.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? I think, your query will work in MySQL.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin, but I run this in PHP and my website on localhost return blank page. Whereas while typing just SELECT * FROM flights, it return everything, just as shown up there.

Comment: @Fengson can you show us the PHP code?

Comment: I just made a simple code to check out if it works, and it doesn't.. Only works when I use SELECT * so.. Here is my code :
http://pastebin.com/JMtk6A4D
Everything needed is added in templates and selectBySQL is a method that takes care of privacy and correct query parsing.

I tried two methods, but commented one in the code.